# Why is keyhelp.ocx failing in my Visual Studio C++ application?

Tags: chm, dep, keyhelp

Using `keyhelp.ocx` to display popup HtmlHelp in a modern Visual Studio C++ application fails.

I get a COM exception with no sensible error code.  Looking at the debug output, there seems to be an Access Violation behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your executable is build with Data Execution Prevention enabled, via `/NXCOMPAT`.  That's the default in Visual Studio.

`keyhelp.ocx` is built using ATL7, which is incompatible with DEP - see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/948468

You need to disable DEP (`/NXCOMPAT:NO`) for your executable or find an alternative to `keyhelp.ocx` (I don't know of one).

(Note that's it's possible to enforce DEP system-wide - your code will still fail on such machines.)